# Match on regexp in assert throws

Tags: javascript, assert, chai

I have a problem with `assert.throws` in `javascript`.

```
assert.throws(() => someFunction(someArgument),
            /string1 (\w+) string2 string 3);
```

I want this expression consistent with `string1 bla bla bla bla string2 string 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` won't match spaces but only letters & digits

Try this instead.

```
string1 ([\w\s]+) string2 string 3
```

`\s` matches blanks (spaces, tabs, CR, LF). You can use `([\w ]+)` in the line above too if you have problems with `\s`

Be careful: lots of strings contain `_` (underscore) not matched by the above. Use `([\w_ ]+)`. And if it doesn't matter what you match between the given strings, just `(.+)`